# How to send request body along with boundary delimiter with the --data option in CURL

Tags: http, curl

I am new to curl.
I am using curl to upload a file using shell script.
I have to set the boundary delimiters explicitly and make an HTTP request by passing few fields.

I have couple of questions:

1. Is it possible to explicitly set boundary delimiters using GET method?
   If yes, how?
2. If not then is it okay to use something like this in a POST method (check the arguments to the --data)

curl --data "**--4ebf00fbcf09**&AB=MSG&tableView=simple&orient=UP&x-895892-n=1
&x-128754-o=2&x-974573-p=1&client=browser&d-984303-s=create&**--4ebf00fbcf09--**"
--header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=4ebf00fbcf09"
www.xyz.com

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those delimiters are used for multipart formposts, and curl will handle the delimiters automatically for you if you just make sure to use [--form](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F) instead of [--data](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d).

The difference between curl's -d and -F is also explained in the curl book in section aptly titled "[-d vs -F](https://ec.haxx.se/http-postvspost.html)".

### The manual way

If you truly want to set the boundary yourself, you need to build the entire formpost yourself as [RFC1867](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt) dictates.

A shell script to send the two values "name=foo" and "value=42":

```
#/bin/sh
boundary="------------------------2100d47bb8839948"

# generate the body
echo "$boundary" > post
echo 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"' >> post
echo "" >> post
echo "foo" >> post
echo "$boundary" >> post
echo 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="value"' >> post
echo "" >> post
echo "42" >> post

## final boundary uses two extra dashes
echo "$boundary--" >> post

curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary" localhost --data-binary @post
```

Comment: Hi, But is there a way to set the delimiter explicitly?